# How to store number in text format in csv file using Ruby CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

Even though I am inserting value as a string in CSV its getting stored as number e.g. "01" getting stored as 1.

I am using CSV writer:

```
@out = File.open("#{File.expand_path("CSV")}/#{file_name}.csv", "w")
CSV::Writer.generate(@out) do |csv|
  csv << ["01", "02", "test"]
end
@out.close
```

This generates csv with given values but when we open csv using excel "01" is not stored as text it gets stored as number

Thanks

Comment: Post a sample of the code you are using. It isn't fair to expect us to guess what you are doing.

Comment: What's the difference between this and your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831366/quote-all-fields-in-csv-output

Answer (score 1):

You have to surround the value with double quotations like `"..."` in order to get it stored as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting:

my_int = 1
p "%02d" % my_int

start here for Ruby 1.9.2

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

and you will see that for a full set of instructions, you need to dig into Kernel::sprintf