# Quote all fields in CSV output

Tags: ruby, csv

```
@out = File.open("#{File.expand_path("CSV")}/#{file_name}.csv", "w")
CSV::Writer.generate(@out) do |csv|
  csv << ["01", "02", "test"]
end
@out.close
```

When i run above code it stores the values in CSV as

01, 02. test

I want them to store as

"01", "02", "test"

Comment: You may want to check out FasterCSV http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/ .  It has the option for specifying the quote character.  I believe it will be the default CSV reader/writer in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @Rob FasterCSV _is_ the `CSV` library that ships in the standard library with 1.9 (and has for a long time now).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change

```
CSV::Writer.generate(@out)do |csv|
```

to

```
CSV::Writer.generate(@out, {:force_quotes=>true}) do |csv|
```

Comment: In case you're on Ruby 1.8.x I would follow @Rob Di Marco's advice and install FasterCSV. It replaced CSV in 1.9.x

Comment: @vasu What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score -3):

So why not double quote them?

```
@out = File.open("#{File.expand_path("CSV")}/#{file_name}.csv", "w")
CSV::Writer.generate(@out) do |csv|
  csv << ['"01"', '"02"', '"test"']
end
@out.close
```

Comment: """01""","""02""","""test"""  this is the output when you open the csv if you double quote them