# Ruby | CSV.generate options "quote_char" does not work

Tags: ruby

By this code.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.generate('', quote_char: '"') { |csv| csv << ['A','B','C'] }
```

It returns this.

```
A,B,C
```

But I expect this result.

```
"A","B","C"
```

## Enviroment

- Ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 6):

Use the `force_quotes` option:

```
puts CSV.generate(quote_char: '"', force_quotes: true) { |csv| csv << ['A','B','C'] }
"A","B","C"
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832131

Answer (score 5):

First, your specification of `quote_char` is redundant, because this is the default.

`quote_char` does **not** say that quotes must be used, but indicates which quotes to use if something needs to be quoted. In your example, no quotes are needed, so you don't see any affect of the quote character.

If you want to have quotes always, you should set `force_quotes: true`.

See for instance [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: Thank you for your great advice! I understand now.